# Quick Start on Tridion Sites Addon development

Tags: add-on

How to start Tridion Site Addon Development
For event handler

Answer (score 3):

Addon service didn't change development part of tridion sites extensions. It changed their deployment (and in some cases configuration).
So you would develop your Event Handler in the same way as before, you would just package it differently in single zip file with new manifest file.

You can find more information about it in docs:

- https://docs.rws.com/956379/545182/tridion-sites-9-6-main-documentation/implementing-add-ons
- https://docs.rws.com/956379/550334/tridion-sites-9-6-main-documentation/event-handler